# can't find a unicode right arrow

Tags: unicode

There are these arrows in Unicode ⬅ ⬆ ⬇ ⬈ ⬉ ⬊ ⬋ ⬌ ⬍

But it's missing a right one.  The name should be something like `RIGHTWARDS BLACK ARROW`, but there's no Unicode character of that name.

There are some char that seems similar, but i couldn't really find the right match.  I'm looking for the right-pointing char of this set.  (based on char name or semantic of the char, not font appearance)

Anyone? I need the Unicode code point.

Here's some of the char's code point

```
character: ⬅ (11013, #o25405, #x2b05)
character: ⬆ (11014, #o25406, #x2b06)
character: ⬍ (11021, #o25415, #x2b0d)
```

Comment: Google for "unicode rightwards black arrow".

Comment: I built a custom search engine for such questions: http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/arrow

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the [Unicode 7.0 Character Code Chart](http://unicode.org/charts/)
for [Miscellaneous Symbols and Arrows](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2B00.pdf):

[image: White and black arrows]
[image: Black arrow]

And from the [Dingbats](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2700.pdf) chart:

[image: Dingbat arrows]

This issue was
[discussed](http://www.unicode.org/mail-arch/unicode-ml/y2013-m10/0074.html) on the
[Unicode Mail List](http://www.unicode.org/mail-arch/), and
[Jukka Korpela](http://www.oreilly.com/pub/au/2537) (author of
*[Unicode Explained](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596101213.do)*)
[mentioned](http://www.unicode.org/mail-arch/unicode-ml/y2013-m10/0075.html):

> My guess is that U+27A1 was included along with other dingbat arrows
>   (which are mostly rightward-pointing arrowlike symbols)
>   because it had been included in legacy character codes.
>   It was then regarded as unnecessary to duplicate it in the
>   Miscellaneous Symbols and Arrows block.
>
> This is somewhat unfortunate.

Here's the timeline of when these characters were added to Unicode:

### 1991

[image: Unicode 1.0]

The Dingbats block (`2700` to `27BF`) has been [present since Unicode 1.0](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode1.0.0/CodeCharts2.pdf). Its characters were copied from the
[ITC Zapf Dingbats](http://www.fonts.com/font/itc/itc-zapf-dingbats) font (released in 1978).

### 2003

[image: Unicode 4.0]

The [Miscellaneous Symbols and Arrows](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/Unicode-4.0/U40-2B00.pdf)
block was [created in Unicode 4.0](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/Unicode-4.0/).

### 2014

The `RIGHTWARDS BLACK ARROW` character (`2B95`) was
[added in Unicode 7.0](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/Unicode-7.0/U70-2B00.pdf).

Comment: superb answer. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent answer. Horror story of the year. Loved the final twist -- that the 2014 right arrow, while being finally the same size as the others, is too recent to be supported by all fonts.

Answer (score 21):

➡ http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27a1/index.htm : &#10145;

Comment: On my machine (Mac OS X Lion), 27A1 is not generally "the same" as 2B05, which is both frustrating and surprising. There are fonts for which they are "the same," but that's not the default behavior.

Comment: In addition, on iOS it's automatically converted to an emotji… which is super annoying (<http://cl.ly/SFRo>).

Comment: In fact, that symbol is named "Black rightwards arrow" and not "Rightwards black arrow", like it should be if it belonged to the same set. They don't really look the same either, just zoom in and you'll see the difference ⬅➡

Comment: @pattulus: try inserting `U+FE0E` after the arrow; it's Variation Selector #15 and its semantics is preventing insertion of coloured emoji (`U+FE0F` is the opposite, it tries to force emoji). Source: http://paulofierro.com/blog/2013/3/30/disabling-emoji-characters-with-unicode-variants

Answer (score 7):

None of those are a thick right arrow that the OP is looking for.  If you go to the wikipedia page for arrows and scroll down to [Miscellaneous Symbols and Arrows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols_and_Arrows), you will see that the OP is exactly right.  There are thick arrows, but no right-hand arrow.

Comment: On that page 0x2b95 *should* be a thick black arrow, but shows as a white box (like other unrecognised characters) on my browser (Chrome under Ubuntu 14.04)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking also a lot for this and finally found it.

You can copy from here directly:  [ ⬅ , ⮕, ⬆ , ⬇ ]